# I keep getting this error in assembly with printing an integer

Tags: assembly

I keep getting a segmentation fault, I can't figure out what the problem is. It is probably something really stupid. I'm just starting to learn assembly so any help and explanation is very welcome!

The exact error is: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
.text
mystr:  .asciz  "%d"    #int that needs to be printed

.global main

main:
    mov 5, %rsi
    mov $mystr, %rdi
    call    printf

end:
    mov $0, %rdi
    call    exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors:

1) A constant has in AT&T-syntax the prefix '$', so you have to write `mov $5, %esi`.

2) The function `printf` needs in `x86-64` an additional argument in `EAX`, that tells the function the amount of vector arguments (e.g. floating point numbers). You have no vector arguments, so add `xor %eax, %eax` before the `call printf`-line.

Answer (score 0):

Your error appears to be that you have a variable `mystr` being assigned in the `.text` section. Now in Assembly, the `.text` is reserved for read only code (which works for basic commands and whatnot and will cause a segmentation fault if you write to it). What you need is a `.data` section which would look something like this:

```
.text
.global main

main:
    mov 5, %rsi
    mov $mystr, %rdi
    call    printf

end:
    mov $0, %rdi
    call    exit

.data
mystr:  .asciz  "%d"    #int that needs to be printed
```

My apologies if this does not compile as is (I am versed in a different kind of Assembly), but the `.data` section is what you are missing.

Comment: That doesn't change anything, I keep getting the same Segmentation fault. Thanks for looking into it though.